# Hide virtual keyboard for fullscreen j2me app

Tags: java-me, touchscreen, lwuit

I developed a J2ME app using LWUIT and it works fine but when I try the app on a mobile phone with Windows Mobile 6 it displays the virtual keyboard overlapping the softkeys until I double clik it.

I already tried to use the following attributes on the application jar but they didn't worked:

```
Navi-Key-Hidden: true
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
```

Does anybody knows if there is the same option for Windows Mobile 6 phones (or other versions) or another hack to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Display.init(this);
    Display.getInstance().setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(null);
```

write this command after Display.init() as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this parameter as well. But be warned, with this jad parameter some nokia devices wont install the application at all.

```
MIDlet-Touch-Support: true
```

And dont forget to run setFullscreen(true) on your Canvas. Some older devices even require that you run it every repaint.

There's also a few LG parameters that might help sometimes;

```
LGE-MIDlet-TargetLCD-Width: 240 

LGE-MIDlet-TargetLCD-Height: 320

LGE-MIDlet-Width: 240

LGE-MIDlet-TargetLCD-Width: 320
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already knew that parameter but it didn't work on the HTC, I think is only for some Samsung and LG devices.